# Android Custom Keyboard Change Background color key pressed

Tags: android, keyboard, key, background-color, pressed

I ve got a problem and could not find a solution till yet! I ve implemented a custom keyboard with several keys. Each key got a background image. I would like to change the background color of the pressed key itself as shown in the original keyboard below:

[image]

I dont want to have a preview, I would like to change the background color of the key itself, when the key gets pressed. Here are my files:

keyboard.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/keyboard"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:keyPreviewOffset="10dp"
android:keyPreviewLayout ="@layout/preview"
android:keyTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
android:keyBackground="@drawable/keybackground"
android:background="#881f2023"
/>
```

keybackground.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/cleanbuttonnormal" />
<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/cleandeactivate" />
<item
    android:state_checkable="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/cleanbuttonnormal" />
<item
    android:state_checkable="true"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/cleandeactivate" />
<item
    android:state_checkable="true"
    android:state_checked="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/cleanbuttonnormal" />
<item
    android:state_checkable="true"
    android:state_checked="true"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/keybackground" />
</selector>
```

The background color will be changed to my drawable, but when I hit the key, it will not changed to the pressed - state. The background stays the same. Could you please help me?

Here my custom keyboard layout, with preview enabled to show that the button got hit.

[image]

The black button with the 8 should get yellow. The preview is for debugging purposed.

Comment: Were you able to achieve the desired results with drawable states list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with your state list in `keybackground.xml`. Here is excerpt from [state list documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList):

> During each state change, the state list is traversed top to bottom
>   and the first item that matches the current state is used—the
>   selection is not based on the "best match," but simply the first item
>   that meets the minimum criteria of the state.

So in your case `<item android:drawable="@drawable/cleanbuttonnormal" />` is selected every time. You should change order of items so the most specific items go first.

Comment: Thanks Alexander for your reply! I understand the problem, but where do I change this? Which files get checked first? How can I set my specific background.xml file as first background? I noticed I made a typo. I corrected the once. I used the keybackground.xml insted of cleanbuttonnormal. Now it looks like my code.

Comment: Just try the reverse order!

Comment: Well thank you! Did not realize this fact. You are right, just moved checked state above and everything is working! Thanks!